# AHK ^{BS}:: gives an error

Tags: autohotkey

I want to execute this script in my program MyLifeOrganized since it's bug. Here is what I want to do:

```
^{Del}::
Send ^{Shift Down}
Send {Left}
Send {Shift Up}
Send {Del}
return
```

What's wrong? It complains on *^{Del}*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `^{Del}` with `^Del`.
Braces (curly brackets) are not used on left side of hotkey definitions.

You can also rewrite your macro as

```
^Del::Send ^+{Down}{Left}+{Up}{Del}
```